# Redux equivalent for Angular2 services

Tags: reactjs, service, redux

I come from an Angular2 world where there are services that do the normal data loading and so on, now I am on a React, Redux application and am trying to figure out what is the equivalent to Angular2 services in Redux (React).  Is it Redux-thunk?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **yes** and **no**.

**Yes**

- Angular services have the logic to load data and normally return a `Promise` object that gets resolved with data loaded.
- With Redux Thunk middleware, you create asynchronous action creators where you put the logic for data loading. But instead of returning a `Promise` object directly, it waits until the data gets resolved and dispatches an action to update the state with data loaded. React components receive data from Redux store via props. (See [`connect()`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) method from `react-redux`.)

**No**

- Angular services are singletons that provides a specific functionality, like `$http` for facilitating communication with the remote HTTP servers.
- Redux Thunk is a middleware and does not do anything but to allow you to write asynchronous action creators that can delay the dispatch of an action, or to dispatch only if a certain condition is met. The action creators are functions that create actions - they are not intended to provide other functionality, like communication with backend servers.

With that said, it is often a matter of coding style where and how you write the logic to load data.

You can use the [`Fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or its [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) function, or [`axios`](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) library, both are `Promise` based. You can also consider using `Observables`, but it is beyond the topic, I think.

As you do with Angular services, you can put all the related logic in a single location and export them. In your action creators, you call these wrapper/helpers, listen for resolution/rejection and dispatch an appropriate action with data resolved as a payload.

Your reducers update the Redux store upon receiving an action dispatched and these state changes are propagated to React components. And this is **how the Flux architecture works** and **how the data flows from Redux Store to React components**, AFAIK.

(I might be wrong, please correct me if anything is incorrect and I am open to your opinions. I am still on the way to figure out the best practice to implement services in React applications.)

Comment: Great answer! the only thing I would change is the bit about calling them "wrapper/helpers".  I do not believe there is an agreed upon term as I've seen them called wrapper, helper, service, client, api and other things I wont repeat as they didn't make much sense.